# How to check a image url is real exist - iOS?

Tags: ios, image, url

In iOS, could I check a `url` if is a real image path?

such as:

1)http://www.imgs.ie/uploads/banners/esb1.png

this is a real `url` path of `image`, but how can I check it is exist in code ?

2)http://www.imgs.ie/uploads/banners/esb2.png

this is a fail `url` path of `image`, but how can I check it is not exist in code ?

**EDIT**

thanks for `rmaddy`'s advice, and my requirement is do not download the `image`, just want to know the url if is a real image url, and just like a `probe` of the url. we can check that.

Comment: Check [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+check+url+exists). And you really need to provide more details in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy， okay, i will

Comment: Still waiting for those additional details in your question. Are you trying to check if the URL exists without actually downloading the image? Please explain exactly what you want. And it would help to indicate what language (Swift/Objective-C).

Comment: If you don't want to download the whole image just to see if it exists, why did you accept an answer that does just that?

Comment: @rmaddy i test the answer. if is a wrong url. i can do the things i want in the else.

Comment: But you stated in your question's update that you didn't want to download the image. You stated you only want to see if it exists or not. If the accepted answer is what you wanted then you should clarify your question because the two don't match at the moment.

Comment: @rmaddy great. i was wrong. too busy

Comment: @rmaddy , I find no way to init a image with url in `swift` to test that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't your try this:

```
var imageURL: NSURL? {
    didSet {
        image = nil
        if view.window != nil {
            fetchImage()
        }
    }
}

private func fetchImage() {
    if let url = imageURL {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            self.spinner?.startAnimating()
            let contentsOfURL = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if url == self.imageURL {
                    if let imageData = contentsOfURL {
                        self.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                    } else {
                        self.spinner?.stopAnimating()
                    }
                } else {
                    print("ignored data returned from url \(url)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when you want to use imageURL:

```
let ImageNames = ["esbn": "http://www.imgs.ie/uploads/banners/esb1.png"]

func getImageNamed(imageName: String?) -> NSURL? {
    if let urlstring = ImageNames[imageName ?? ""] {
        return NSURL(string: urlstring)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

imageURL = getImageNamed(imageName: imageName)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uiimage *image = [uiimage imagewithurl:@"your url"];
if(image){
//exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alamofire :

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, completeURLImage).response { (request, response, data, error) in
 if data != nil{
     imgView.image = UIImage(data: data!, scale: 1)
    }
}
```